# BCELoss().backward throws Runtime Error or doesn't train with Requires_grad

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch and am running into an error with optimizing an `nn.Embedding` matrix.

My code below, with given variables `embedding_dim`, `num_node`, `train_label` and `train_edge`:

```
emb = nn.Embedding(num_node, embedding_dim)
optimizer = SGD(emb.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()
sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

for i in range(500):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  res = torch.FloatTensor([sigmoid(torch.dot(emb(a), emb(b))) for (a, b) in zip(train_edge[0], train_edge[1])])
  loss = loss_fn(res, train_label)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
  print(f'loss:{loss}')
```

runs into a RuntimeError at `loss.backward()`:

`RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

If I add `requires_grad=True` to the assignment of `res`, the Runtime Error disappears, but the optimizer doesn't train / the loss doesn't decrease. Any idea what might I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error raises clearly due to `res` not having `.requires_grad` on.

Since you are making a Tensor from a list of Tensors, its better to use `torch.cat` and not `torch.FloatTensor`. The latter is for *constructing* a tensor and do not have `.requires_grad=True` by default.

---

If it does not train (non-decreasing loss as you mentioned), that may be due to other reasons (data, wrong hyperparameters etc.) which seems to be out of scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to make the backpropagation flow from the loss term to the model's parameters, *i.e.* `emb`. By using `torch.Tensor` to define `res`, you are copying the content of your list comprehension into a data buffer. Using `requires_grad` on `res` won't change the problem since `emb` is applied ***before*** `res` is defined, what's more, is you are not looking to compute the gradient of `res`.

What you need is to require the gradient on the inputs of the model *i.e.* here it seems to be `train_edge`. This being said, it is usually a good practice to use a combination of [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) and [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), which will handle that for you.